# faq currently discriminates against older consoles

Tags: support, faq-proposed

The [gaming.se FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) currently reads:

> Gaming - Stack Exchange is for
>   passionate videogamers from all
>   platforms, including consoles and
>   computers. If your question generally
>   covers …
>   - PC video gaming
>   - Xbox, PS3, Wii gaming
>   - Nintendo DS, PSP, iPhone gaming
>   … then you are in the right place to ask your question!

and then goes on to talk about game-rec. This seems to imply that if you have a question about older consoles, you are *not* in the right place. I don't think this is intentional.

Can we alter this to avoid naming specific consoles, or is there a good reason to keep it as is?

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, why not add "e.g." and one older console somewhere, like

> Gaming - Stack Exchange is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles and computers. If your question generally covers …
>   - PC video gaming
>   - Video Console (e.g. Xbox, PS3, Wii, SNES...) gaming
>   - Handheld (e.g. Nintendo DS, PSP, iPhone, Gameboy, ...) gaming
>   … then you are in the right place to ask your question!

(Sorry for Nintendo specific examples, that're the ones I used to own)

Comment: Should I put this on the FAQ for now, or wait until I get some more word that we're fine on this distribution? (Wow, hosed by the enter button.)

Answer (score 6):

I would say yo keep the first lines up-to date with the latest and geatest, as thi serves as a confirmation that, yes we indeed serve these type of devices such as iPhone gaming (which also covers android gaming  BTW ;) ) and adding a line stating we also support the older ones

> Gaming - Stack Exchange is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles and computers. If your question generally covers …
>
> - PC video gaming
> - Xbox, PS3, Wii gaming
> - Nintendo DS, PSP, iPhone gaming
> - … or gaming on any of the older devices (like arcade cabinets, Commodore 64, NES or the GameBoy)
>
> … then you are in the right place to ask your question!

I used the most notable devices from the history of gaming to build the last devices line.

Comment: I like this idea.  Rather than trying to *imply* that we support older devices by including one or two in the list, this explicitly states it, backed up with examples.